# How to use Mirror to access externally defined class?

Tags: ios, swift, reflection, cocoapods, mirror

I'm trying to `Mirror` this class:

```
final class DeckPresentationController {
    ...
}
```

defined by the [`DeckTransition` CocoaPod](https://github.com/HarshilShah/DeckTransition/blob/master/DeckTransition/Classes/DeckPresentationController.swift), so I  can change some var, but the mirror didn't reflect anything to me:

```
import DeckTransition

let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: DeckPresentationController())
print("children: \(mirror.children.first)")
print("count: \(mirror.children.count) ")
```

gives this compiling error:

> unresolved identifier DeckPresentationController

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: import DeckTransition
let aMirror = Mirror(reflecting: DeckPresentationController())
# unresolved identifier "DeckPresentationController"

Comment: This doesn't look like`Mirror` issue at all — you need *first* to be able to create a `DeckPresentationController` instance ;)

Comment: DeckPresentationController is final class and I can't reach it by anyway ?

Comment: It needs to be marked a `public` or `open` class to be visible *outside* the corresponding pod/module. The `final` modifier doesn't affect visibility at all.

Comment: Umm, it's not `open` nor `public`,in short you're saying this is impossible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146673/discussion-between-mohammad-eliass-alhusain-and-paulo-mattos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access an `internal` class declared in an *external* module. As such, using `Mirror` won't get you there as well — you *can't* hack Swift access control using reflection like that ;)

As a quick hack, change the [class declaration](https://github.com/HarshilShah/DeckTransition/blob/master/DeckTransition/Classes/DeckPresentationController.swift) from:

```
final class DeckPresentationController
```

to:

```
open class DeckPresentationController
```

and then access/override the desired properties directly — and forget about that hack-ish `Mirror` of yours ;)

By the way, if your edit might be useful to others as well, consider submitting a *pull request* to the original CocoaPod author.

Comment: please can you give me any documentation for mirror types that should be open or public not private !

Comment: You may need to promote some vars to `public` as well depending on your requirements.